# Recruiter asks for curriculum without providing details about the job offer

Tags: resume, recruitment, linkedin

### Context

I recently got contacted by a recruiter on Linkedin with a message similar to this:

> Hi ...,
>
> my name is ... and I'm a recruiter for company *X*, an engineering company that works across Europe and USA.
>
> your skills are potentially interesting for our company so I'd like you to send us your updated curriculum, so that I can share it with my business manager and possibly we'll contact you back for more information.
>
> ... thank you ...

I replied that I don't mind sharing my curriculum, but I would like to know more about the open job position(s) for which my skills are interesting. The reply from the recruiter was:

> Your profile looks interesting for your skills in cyber security and software development. If you don't mind, please share your curriculum with us, even for future opportunities.

### Question

Is it still a good idea to send my curriculum (since the recruiter didn't provide the information I requested)?

### Background

I currently have a full-time job and, although I'm not actively looking for new jobs, I'm open to new opportunities. The company is legit and so is the recruiter, but since I was not given the additional information I requested, I'm somewhat reluctant to send my curriculum.

Comment: What do you want from the exchange with the recruiter? If you find that out, you can find a plan for how to act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there isn't a job - *yet*. That doesn't mean there won't be in the future.

Given this is coming from an internal recruiter at a company rather than an agency, the usual concerns that they are just harvesting CVs for the database of people to hit up with emails/phone calls every time a potential match becomes available is lessened.

Most likely there's some internal discussions going on about possibly recruiting someone with the skills they've mentioned and someone's asked the recruiter to have a preliminary look at who's out there. They aren't giving you details about the position yet either because there aren't details yet, the details haven't been given to the recruiter or a mixture of the two.

> Is it still a good idea to send...

If you're confident that they are who they say they are there's no real downside to sending it but I'd do it with fairly minimal expectations. If something comes of it then all good.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are not actively looking, ignore it. Unlikely to get anywhere
- Check whether the recruiter is actually an employee of the company or from an indepdent agency. If it's agency, tell them to go away. They are just harvesting resumes for their database.
- If it's a company employee, check out the company and see of your are interested and whether it's a reputable/desirable things. If yes, consider sending it